# Botón no envia formulario

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un formulario y tengo un error que no soy capaz de detectar. Con un bucle creo un listado, y en cada vuelta de ese bucle abro y cierro una etiqueta `<form>` para poder modificar los datos que contiene cada vuelta. Pues bien, visualmente lo veo todo correcto, sin embargo al pulsar el botón de guardar no hace nada, no envía el formulario. He probado a ponerle type="submit" y tampoco, ¿Sabeis porque?

Ahí va mi código:

```php
$consulta_escandallo = $Produccion->listarlineasEscandallos("");
if($coes = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_escandallo)){
           echo '<div class="card"><div class="card-body"><table id="html5-escandallo" class="table table-bordered  dataTable table-responsive" role="grid">';
           echo '<thead class="thead-dark"><tr role="row">
         <th >Referencia</th>
         <th >Nombre</th>
         <th >Cantidad</th>
         <th>Unidad medida</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
           </tr> </thead>';
           echo '
         <tbody>';
      do{
           $ides = $coes['id'];
           $idart = $coes['id_articulo'];
           $datos_articulo = new Articulos(intval($idart));
           $cantidad = $coes['cantidad'];
           $idum = $coes['unidad_medida'];
           echo '<form method="POST"><tr role="row">
         <td scope="row">'.$datos_articulo->referencia.'</td>
         <td scope="row">'.$datos_articulo->nombre.'</td>
         <td scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="id_linea" value="'.$ides.'">
         <input type="hidden" name="id_articulo" value="'.$idart.'">
         <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" name="cantidad_linea" id="cantidad_linea" value="'.$cantidad.'"></td>
         <td scope="row">
             ';
             $comprobar_um = $Produccion->listarUM("");
             if($clium = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_um)) {
                  echo '<select name="um_linea"  id="um_linea" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">';
                 do {
                   $idumlin = $clium['id'];
                   if($idum == $idumlin){
                   $marcaum = "selected";
                   }else{
                   $marcaum = "";
                   }
                   echo '<option '.$marcaum.' value="'.$clium['id'].'">'.$clium['nombre'].'</option>';
                 }while($clium = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_um));
                   echo '</select>';
                 }
          echo'
         </td>
         '; ?>
         <td ><button  class="btn btn-dark pull-right" >Guardar cambios</button></td>
         <td ><button type="button" name="borrar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick= "borrarID1(<?=$coes['id']?>,15)">Borrar</button></td>
           <?php echo'
         </tr></form>';
      }while($coes = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_escandallo)); 
echo '</tbody></table></div></div></a>';
```

Comment: Veo un evento `onclick` en el botón. ¿Se encarga de realizar alguna petición? ¿O es mera funcionalidad del frontend?

Comment: Hola Francisco, tienes un par de errores no estas cerrando bien las estructuras, el If principal no esta cerrado. Luego cierras la etiqueta de php y luego la abres. Convendría que revisaras el código. Gracias.

Comment: En la etiqueta form le falta el action donde queres que vaya el formulario`<form action='urldestino'></form>`

tambien podes por javascript asignarle diferente funciones a cada boton. 
``

Comment: Consejo para mejorar la legibilidad: no uses `echo` para enviar HTML al documento. En su lugar cierra PHP combinado con la [sintaxis alternativa de las estructuras de control](https://www.php.net/control-structures.alternative-syntax). El código quedará mejor estructurado y, además, tu editor de código podrá resaltar mejor tanto el HTML como el código PHP, quedando ambos convenientemente seaparados. Nota: Además, procura usar `<?= htmlspecialchars(...) ?>` en vez de simplemente `<?= ... ?>` para evitar los incómodos problemas del [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad es que este error "Tonto" me ha dado muchos problemas, y al final lo he solucionado (Pongo como por si a alguien más le pasa). La solución al final ha estado moviendo la apertura y cierre del  dentro de la etiqueta .

Gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas!

Comment: Buenos días. Por favor, para publicar actualizaciones acerca de tu pregunta es mejor dejar un comentario bajo ella o bien hacer una edición. Si ésta es la respuesta y quieres dejarla como tal, entonces sería conveniente publicar el código corregido que acompañe a la explicación. Además, también vendría bien una reflexión del motivo por el que haber movido la etiqueta de cierre provocó que dejara de funcionar como esperabas.